# Sidekiq / Ruby On Rails - Lock using Redis (Redlock) not locking correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq, redlock

I'm trying to lock a part of my code using Redis, with [Redlock library](https://github.com/leandromoreira/redlock-rb).

I've implemented it here:

```
def perform(task_id, task_type)

 lock_manager = Redlock::Client.new([ "redis://127.0.0.1:6379" ])

 lock_key = "task_runnuer_job_#{task_type}_#{task_id}"

 puts("locking! #{task_id}")

 lock_task = lock_manager.lock(lock_key , 6 * 60 * 1000)

if lock_task.present?

  begin
    
    # Exec task...

    Services::ExecTasks::Run.call task.id

   ensure
     puts("unlocking! #{task_id}")
     lock_manager.unlock(lock_task)
   end

 else
      puts("Resource is locked! #{lock_key}")
 end

 end
```

What I get when running multiple Sidekiq jobs at the same time, is the following logs:

```
"locking! 520"
"locking! 520"
"unlocking! 520"
"unlocking! 520"
```

This happens when both of my 520 task, which should not be executed together, are being called with 1ms diffrence.

Yet sometimes the lock works as expected.

I've checked Redis and it works just fine.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could it be you have different types?

Comment: Apparently I had another piece of code that wasn’t affected by the lock, due to existing in a slightly different environment.